# Problem with column centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I got a problem I really can't understand. I am trying to have all the number in each columns centered but it is working only for the first two rows of each panel (Treatment and subsequent one) while it doesn't apply to the other two (Bandwidth and Obs). Any hint?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,dcolumn,adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,skip=.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Reduced form regressions for labour market outcomes}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{7}{d{2.5}} cc @{}} 
\toprule
 & \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} \\
\addlinespace
Outcome & \mC{Employed} 
        & \mC{Agricultural Job} 
        & \mC{Non Agric. Job}
        & \mC{Service Job}
        & \mC{Occasionally Employed}
        & \mC{Paid job}
        & \mC{Self Employed}\\ 
\midrule
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{Linear model with optimal bandwidth \hat{h}}} \\
\hline
Treatment & 0.0145 & 0.0324 &-0.0109 & 0.00249 &  0.0119 & -0.0506  & 0.00976 \\
 & (0.0236)  & (0.0264) & (0.0217) & (0.00553) & (0.00997)  &(0.0336)& (0.0253)  \\ 
 Bandwidth & 33 & 31 & 54 & 42 & 30 & 35 & 35\\ 
 Obs & 4,490 & 4,200 & 7,649 & 5,854 & 4,065 & 4,739& 4,739\\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{Quadratic model with optimal bandwidth \hat{h}}} \\
\hline
Treatment & 0.0149 & 0.0324 & -0.0131& 0.00228 & 0.0127 & -0.0516 & 0.0101\\
 & (0.0235) & (0.0261) & (0.0224) & (0.00554) & (0.00997)  & (0.0323)& (0.0254)  \\ 
 Bandwidth & 33 & 31 & 54 & 42 & 30 & 35 & 35\\ 
 Obs & 4,490 & 4,200 & 7,649 & 5,854 &  4,065& 4,739&4,739 \\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{Linear model with bandwidth 2\hat{h} }} \\
\hline
Treatment & 0.0205 & 0.0237 & -0.00695& 0.00705  & 0.00767 & -0.0739^{*} &  0.0361\\
 & (0.0269) & (0.0282) & (0.0316) &(0.00735) &(0.00715) & (0.0402) & (0.0303)  \\ 
 Bandwidth & 66 & 62 & 108 & 84 & 60 & 70 & 70\\ 
 Obs & 2,200 & 2,022 & 3,640 & 2,927 &  2,022 & 2,332&2,332 \\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{Linear model with bandwidth 2\hat{h}/3}} \\
\hline
Treatment & 0.0330 & 0.0313 & -0.0171 & 0.00941 &  0.00853 & -0.0543 & 0.0247 \\
 & (0.0271) & (0.0295) & (0.0288) &(0.00609) & (0.0113)& (0.0374) & (0.0309)  \\ 
 Bandwidth & 22 & 20 & 36 & 28 & 20 & 23 & 23\\ 
 Obs & 3,027 & 2,927 & 4,866 & 3,801 &  2,797& 3,027&3,027 \\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{Linear model with bandwidth 2\hat{h}}} \\
\hline
Treatment & 0.0192 & 0.0297 & 0.00693 & 0.000796 & 0.00400 & -0.00176 & 0.0134\\
 & (0.0174) & (0.0200) & (0.0150) & (0.00396) & (0.00763) & (0.0219) & (0.0174)  \\ 
 Bandwidth & 16 & 15 & 27 & 21 & 15 & 17 & 17\\ 
 Obs & 9,403 & 8,751 & 15,632 & 12,064 &  8,499 & 9,953 & 9,953\\
 \addlinespace
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ $^{***}\ p<0.01$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{*}\  p<0.1$} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and this is an example of what I am getting
[image]

Comment: Actually it's working perfectly as you ask for decimal-aligned cells and they are aligned at the `.`!

Comment: The example produces the error `! Missing $ inserted.` because `\hat` is mis-used. The  text accent is `\^{h}` or (in this case better it is math so `$\hat{h}$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to align all four rows so I switched to a different column format for the integer valued rows

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,dcolumn,adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,skip=.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\newcommand\ic[1]{\multicolumn{1}{D..{6.2}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{Reduced form regressions for labour market outcomes}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{7}{d{2.6}} cc @{}} 
\toprule
 & \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} \\
\addlinespace
Outcome & \mC{Employed} 
        & \mC{Agricultural\\ Job} 
        & \mC{Non Agric\\. Job}
        & \mC{Service Job}
        & \mC{Occasionally\\ Employed}
        & \mC{Paid job}
        & \mC{Self\\ Employed}\\ 
\midrule
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{Linear model with optimal bandwidth $\hat{h}$}} \\
\hline
Treatment & 0.0145 & 0.0324 &-0.0109 & 0.00249 &  0.0119 & -0.0506  & 0.00976 \\
 & (0.0236)  & (0.0264) & (0.0217) & (0.00553) & (0.00997)  &(0.0336)& (0.0253)  \\ 
 Bandwidth & \ic{33} & \ic{31} & \ic{54} & \ic{42} & \ic{30} & \ic{35} & \ic{35}\\ 
 Obs & \ic{4,490} & \ic{4,200} & \ic{7,649} & \ic{5,854} & \ic{4,065} & \ic{4,739}& \ic{4,739}\\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{Quadratic model with optimal bandwidth $\hat{h}$}} \\
\hline
Treatment & 0.0149 & 0.0324 & -0.0131& 0.00228 & 0.0127 & -0.0516 & 0.0101\\
 & (0.0235) & (0.0261) & (0.0224) & (0.00554) & (0.00997)  & (0.0323)& (0.0254)  \\ 
 Bandwidth & \ic{33} & \ic{31} & \ic{54} & \ic{42} & \ic{30} & \ic{35} & \ic{35}\\ 
 Obs & \ic{4,490} & \ic{4,200} & \ic{7,649} & \ic{5,854} &  \ic{4,065}& \ic{4,739}&\ic{4,739} \\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{Linear model with bandwidth $2\hat{h}$ }} \\
\hline
Treatment & 0.0205 & 0.0237 & -0.00695& 0.00705  & 0.00767 & -0.0739^{*} &  0.0361\\
 & (0.0269) & (0.0282) & (0.0316) &(0.00735) &(0.00715) & (0.0402) & (0.0303)  \\ 
 Bandwidth & \ic{66} & \ic{62} & \ic{108} & \ic{84} & \ic{60} & \ic{70} & \ic{70}\\ 
 Obs & \ic{2,200} & \ic{2,022} & \ic{3,640} & \ic{2,927} &  \ic{2,022} & \ic{2,332}&\ic{2,332} \\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{Linear model with bandwidth $2\hat{h}/3$}} \\
\hline
Treatment & 0.0330 & 0.0313 & -0.0171 & 0.00941 &  0.00853 & -0.0543 & 0.0247 \\
 & (0.0271) & (0.0295) & (0.0288) &(0.00609) & (0.0113)& (0.0374) & (0.0309)  \\ 
 Bandwidth & \ic{22} & \ic{20} & \ic{36} & \ic{28} & \ic{20} & \ic{23} & \ic{23}\\ 
 Obs & \ic{3,027} & \ic{2,927} & \ic{4,866} & \ic{3,801} &  \ic{2,797}& \ic{3,027}&\ic{3,027} \\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{Linear model with bandwidth $2\hat{h}$}} \\
\hline
Treatment & 0.0192 & 0.0297 & 0.00693 & 0.000796 & 0.00400 & -0.00176 & 0.0134\\
 & (0.0174) & (0.0200) & (0.0150) & (0.00396) & (0.00763) & (0.0219) & (0.0174)  \\ 
 Bandwidth & \ic{16} & \ic{15} & \ic{27} & \ic{21} & \ic{15} & \ic{17} & \ic{17}\\ 
 Obs & \ic{9,403} & \ic{8,751} & \ic{15,632} & \ic{12,064} &  \ic{8,499} & \ic{9,953} & \ic{9,953}\\
 \addlinespace
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ $^{***}\ p<0.01$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{*}\  p<0.1$} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```